# Laying Search Bar on Image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put my search bar on top of my image and I'm not too sure what I'm missing. I've tried to change the positions, for the search bar and it seems like it isn't doing much except moving it around outside of the image.

```css
.headerNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #601F27;
}

.headerNav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.headerNav li {
    float: left;
}

.headerNav a {
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.headerNav a:hover {
    background: #f9d4cc;
}

.container {
    margin: 1.2rem 10rem 1rem 10rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    height: 425px;
    width: 1500px;
}

form {
    width:500px;
    /*margin:0 auto;*/
    position:relative; 
    z-index: -1;
}
.search { 
    padding:0px 200px 25px 0px;
    margin:0px; 
}

input[type=text] {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}

input[type=button], input[type=button]:hover {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px;
    border:1px solid #adc5cf;
    background: #e4f1f9; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e4f1f9), color-stop(100%,#d5e7f3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%,#d5e7f3 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e4f1f9', endColorstr='#d5e7f3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color:#7da2aa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dark {
    width:95%;
    height:50px;
    padding:0px 0px;
}

.dark input[type=text] {
    border:1px solid #2a2e31;
    background-color:#2d3035;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerNav">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="account.html">Log In / Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="dark">
        <form>
            <span><input type="text" class="search square"><input type="button" value="Search"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help with this problem ? My html/css isn't that great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an absolute position to the image `position: absolute;` and a z-index onto the search `z-index: 1;`

```css
.headerNav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #601F27;
}
.headerNav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.headerNav li {
  float: left;
}
.headerNav a {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.headerNav a:hover {
  background: #f9d4cc;
}
.container {
  margin: 1.2rem 10rem 1rem 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  height: 425px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: absolute;
}
/* search bar */

form {
  width: 500px;
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.search {
  padding: 0px 200px 25px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
input[type=text] {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}
input[type=button],
input[type=button]:hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #adc5cf;
  background: #e4f1f9;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e4f1f9), color-stop(100%, #d5e7f3));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #e4f1f9 0%, #d5e7f3 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e4f1f9', endColorstr='#d5e7f3', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  color: #7da2aa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dark {
  width: 95%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
.dark input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #2a2e31;
  background-color: #2d3035;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerNav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="account.html">Log In / Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="dark">
      <form>
        <span><input type="text" class="search square"><input type="button" value="Search"></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Once I did that, my search bar disappeared.

Comment: I see the search bar is inside my form, but is there anyway to bring it above the picture I have ?

Comment: You need to set a position to the image not the bar.

Comment: I have set the image itself to position:absolute but the image still overlays the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

If the image to be the background, you should add it as a `background-image` in CSS, not as `<image/>` tag in HTML.

Comment: The image only shows, inside a div at a specific area. Not a complete background image.

Answer (score -1):

Better way is set dark class position absolute and position it (left , top) as your need.

Also you have to container class position relative.